# A function returning multiple types comma separated . What is it in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to Typescript I came across the following syntax

```
interface Foo {

    // what is age is here and 
    // what if it is not optional i.e () => string, age:number;

    (): () => string, age?: number;
}
```

What I have understood Foo is a function interface,  any function that implements Foo must return a function that must return a string.

but what age?: number is for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's clearer to understand with a line break, and a semicolon instead of comma (I'm intrigued that the comma is valid, but according to the playground, it is):

```
interface Foo {
    (): () => string;
    age?: number;
}
```

`Foo` defines an interface for a function that:

- Returns a function that returns a `string`, and
- Has an optional `age` property that's a `number`.

More about function types [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types).

Here's an example of it in use:

```
interface Foo {
    (): () => string,
    age?: number;
}

const f: Foo = () => () => "foo";
f.age = 42; // Note this is on the function
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=12#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIAUAlAFzEnIC8AfMgM5hSgDmANPoXKxAPwUQAVwC2AI2gBuXAF9cuBOhBNkMChizVKNeqR3IARDEwHpMAHQ8UWgCwAmSUA)

Fair to say that's an...*interesting*...interface. :-)

Comment: Ohh my god that was a silly question, I got confused because of it was written in single line. Thanks a lot. By the way should I use "semicolon" or "comma" at the end of statement while declaring members ?

Comment: @manas - I didn't think it was silly at all, took me a minute to figure it out (and even then I got it slightly wrong at first). I just updated the answer (I was in the middle of doing that when I had to go run an errand :-) ). I was surprised the comma worked. I've always used semicolons.